# javascript: document.write function have redefined, how can I recover it

Tags: javascript

When I visit some website(such as: https://www.baidu.com) and open browser dev tool, I found they have redefined function "document.write" as:

```js
document.write
//output: ƒ (){}
```

yes, they have replaced "document.write" with a "blank" function.
So my question is: how can I recover "document.write" to original function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per baidu javascript code `document.write` is rewritten with empty function. In code it's written as `document.write = document.writeln = function() {}`

`document` is instance of `Document`, we can assign `Document.prototype.write` to `document.write` it'll update function to its default. Below is the sample code snippet to override function to use it's default standard
`document.write = Document.prototype.write`